# Create python list comprehension from sparse data

Tags: python, list-comprehension, sparse-matrix

I have two lists (keys and values) that define a single sparsely defined list with values at every key location. I want to convert this to a dense list with values in every location.  I can do this with a for loop as follows.

```
keys = [1,3,5]
values = [1.0, 3.0, 5.0]
column = [None]*10
for i, k in enumerate(keys):
    column[k] = values[i]

column
>>> [None, 1.0, None, 3.0, None, 5.0, None, None, None, None]
```

Is it possible to create column using a list comprehension?

Comment: `column = [values[i] if i in keys else None for i in range(10)]` seems like the natural approach, but I'm not 100% sure if Python will accept the indexing properly on the `values[i]` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
keys = [1,3,5]
values = [1.0, 3.0, 5.0]

column = [values[keys.index(i)] if i in keys else None for i in range(10)]

print(column)
```

**Output**

```
[None, 1.0, None, 3.0, None, 5.0, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: Doesn't `if i in keys` become an O(n) search for each item? That would be a problem when keys gets very large.

Comment: no you are wrong, you can check it if you want, for example `lst = list(range(1000000))`  `999999 in lst` will take less than one second, result that time give to me is ~ `0.04346823692321777 seconds`

Comment: Check my answer below with timings. I would be glad to be shown my error. I started with a size of 1M and killed it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use this one-liner `list comprehension`:

```
column =[None if i not in dict(zip(keys,values)).keys() else dict(zip(keys,values))[i] for i in range(10)]
```

Output:

```
[None, 1.0, None, 3.0, None, 5.0, None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

I accepted zimdero's answer above as it definitely answers the question. However, there was a question about timing on large lists. I used the used the code below to time each case with a list size of 10K and a density of .4 (60% of the values are None).

For this particular case, the for loop is 2 orders of magnitude faster than list comprehension and over 3 orders of magnitude faster than the list comprehension using zip. See the results below.

```
import time
import random

# setup test case
iterations = 10
sz = 10000
cutoff = sz*.60
a = random.sample(range(1,sz+1), sz)
dense = [x if x > cutoff else None for x in a]
keys = [i for i, n in enumerate(dense) if n]
values = [x for x in dense if x]

# case 1 for loop
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(iterations):
    column = [None]*sz
    for i, k in enumerate(keys):
        column[k] = values[i]

end_time = time.time()
print("For loop time            :", end_time - start_time)


# case 2 list comprehension
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(iterations):
    column = [values[keys.index(i)] if i in keys else None for i in range(sz)]
end_time = time.time()

print("List comprehension time 1:", end_time - start_time)


# case 2 list comprehension
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(iterations):
    column =[None if i not in dict(zip(keys,values)).keys() else 
dict(zip(keys,values))[i] for i in range(sz)]
end_time = time.time()

print("List comprehension time 2:", end_time - start_time)



For loop time            : 0.00599980354309082 
List comprehension time 1: 6.379000186920166 
List comprehension time 2: 36.09299993515015
```

Comment: it is because- 1) `len(keys) == 4000` `iteration * 4000 == 40000 iterations` this is in your for loop, in out for lop `sr == 10000` `iteration * sz == 100000 iterations` 2) in your for loop you simple modify your list, but in our case with `list comprehension` we create new list `column` not modify old one, also we check if `i` is in `keys` also after this we take `keys.index(i)` this also take time, no always `list comprehesion` is the best choice in this case better to use simple for loop statment i think